# Application Context returns instance of org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler instead of org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean

Tags: spring, quartz

I am trying to use quartz scheduler with spring and trying to create bean of SchedulerFactoryBean, I have added below entry in spring bean xml but it always returns StdScheduler instance instead of SchedulerFactoryBean.

```xml
<beans:bean id="corescheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean" scope="prototype" lazy-init="true" destroy-method="destroy">
```

I am getting below error when getting a bean from application context.

```
SchedulerFactoryBean coreScheduler = (SchedulerFactoryBean) applicationContext.getBean("corescheduler");
```

**Error:**
org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler cannot be cast to org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean

Can anyone please help ?

Answer (score 0):

That is a perfectly normal behavior. Please check Spring docs to see how Spring factory beans work in general.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/SchedulerFactoryBean.html#getObject-- and you will find out this factory bean creates and returns org.quartz.Scheduler instances.

Comment: Thanks Moravec for your reply, but it should return Scheduler instance when getObject method is called right and not while creating an bean of SchedulerFactoryBean itself ?

Comment: No, Spring factory beans are used as factories. It means, Spring first creates an (internal) instance of a factory bean and then invokes its getObject method which is what your application gets when it calls appContext.getBean("someFactoryBeanId").